# Create a "Products Listing" page that embeds a context-aware View of specific type of products

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, cck

I have the following page structure:

```
Product listing for type 1
|-> Product 1.1
|-> Product 1.2
...
Product listing for type 2
|-> Product 2.1
|-> Product 2.2
...
```

so I have created a content-type "Generic_Product_Listing" which has a field_type and would like to embed a view that only gets the products of that specific type.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [Viewfield](http://drupal.org/project/viewfield) module is what you need?